# Doctor Who reading

Tags: doctor-who

I'm doing a reading at my friends' wedding and he is a massive Doctor Who fan. Does anyone have any ideas for a Doctor Who themed reading of a decent length?

Comment: Dearly beloved, we are gathered here yesterday...

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic for Stack Exchange. You might have better luck on a suitable subreddit. Make sure you mention *which* Doctor is your friend's favourite, that will have a big impact on the answers.

Comment: Believe it or not, almost the same question has been asked on this site before :-) I've linked your question as a duplicate instead of closing it outright as off-topic - maybe some of the answers over there will be useful for you.